# MOSFET Vg not zero?

Tags: mosfet

I have this simple circuit with a 5V power source, a MOSFET, a diode and a resistor.

[image]

With the diode already blocking, how come Vg isn't 0V but 2.06V? If the circuit is modified to become this, Vg is then 0V:

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What's with all those yellow blocks all over your schematic?  Too annoying, no thanks.

Comment: Haha this is falstad simulator @Olin Lathrop the yellow represent animated electrons, which actually move. Very intuitive visualisation of how current is flowing!

Comment: Play with the toys all you want, but when you are presenting a schematic for others to see, you need to follow the conventions of schematics.  Loose the yellow turds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you assume the the diode is fully blocking all current, then the MOSFET gate is floating. There is nothing to make a floating node automatically prefer 0V.  It would read as 0V on a multimeter because meters include a high resistance (10Mohm+) in parallel.

However, diodes do not block all current flow: if there is any voltage across the diode (forward or reverse) then some amount of current will pass through it from the higher voltage side to the lower voltage side.  So in a steady state, the voltage on the left side of the diode should equal the voltage on the right side of the diode, and the current through the diode will be 0.